# How to detect when a player is wearing a chest plate with a specific name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I was attempting to make a jetpack in Minecraft with commands. At first I just thought that you would hold an item (which I decided to use a chainmail chestplate) named "Jetpack" and it would work. So I did that and it all worked perfectly, but then I thought that you should wear the chestplate, then hold an item called "Jetpack Controller" to activate it instead. I looked on this forum and I tried a bunch of stuff and it doesn't work for my specific situation. I want to give a scoreboard tag to everyone wearing a chain chestplate named Jetpack so that I can then use that in an execute command along with the tag that detects when you're holding the Jetpack Controller.

Comment: Please provide the command you tried for detecting the equiped chestplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will add a [scoreboard tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags) to any players who have the named chestplate equipped and are currently holding any item named "Jetpack Controller".

This will require a [command block chain](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#Chained_execution).  The first command block removes the tag from anyone who previously got tagged but no longer meet the conditions. The second command block tags the players who currently meet the conditions.

These command blocks have to remain loaded at all times.  I recommend putting them in the [spawn chunk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_chunk).  I also recommend stopping command block output to prevent chat spam for op players. To do this, use command:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

The first command block is <kbd>Repeat</kbd> <kbd>Unconditional</kbd> <kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a remove Equipped
```

The second command block is <kbd>Chain</kbd> <kbd>Unconditional</kbd> <kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a add Equipped {Inventory:[{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:chainmail_chestplate",tag:{display:{Name:"Jetpack"}}}],SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"Jetpack Controller"}}}}
```

Now you can target those players for other commands using the [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors) with a [tag argument](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_tag):

```
@a[tag=Equipped]
```

For fun, lets make them all talk about their jetpacks:

```
/execute @a[tag=Equipped] ~ ~ ~ say I have my jetpack on
```

Now you can use this tag in your jetpack system.

**Note**: The selected item portion of the command does not contain the `id` element so any item named "Jetpack Controller" will satisfy it.  If you want it to be a specific item, you will have to add that data to the command.